# CSS Formatting changes with font stye

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a modal displaying a list of logs as shown below.

```
<div id="showSanity" class="modal">
    <div class="infobox1" >
        <div class="container" style="white-space:pre-wrap;" id="logs">
            {{ testLog.val }}
        </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="okbutton"><button id="logsOkButton">OK</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My heading remains in place in the centre if my font-style is Arial.But,  heading moves to the right if I set my font-style to monospace.

```
.infobox1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #eceeee;
  border: 1px solid #42464b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family:monospace;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  align-items: centre;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Can I know where I am going wrong?

Comment: instead of `align-items: centre;` have you tried `text-align:center;`?

Answer (score 0):

for this your have to remove `white-space:pre-wrap;` from `container` div & add `text-align: center;` to `infobox1` div.
check updated snippet below..

```css
.infobox1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #eceeee;
  border: 1px solid #42464b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  font-style: normal;
  /*font-family:monospace;*/
  font-family:arial;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="showSanity" class="modal">
    <div class="infobox1" >
        <div class="container" id="logs">
            {{ testLog.val }}
        </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="okbutton"><button id="logsOkButton">OK</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention..sorry. That I am trying to print a long string with newline characters in between the strings. If I do what you suggested, then my entire string is showing up in a single line without any newlines.

Comment: @NagireddyHanisha In that case you can add `word-wrap: break-word` to wrap your long string

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: pre-wrap`
mean every character will be shown including white space.

A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with variable-width fonts, where the letters and spacings have different widths. [Read more about monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

So when you use monospace font family your white space width is bigger than the regular Arial font.

remove extra white space or tab before

`<div class="container" style="white-space:pre-wrap;" id="logs">
    {{ testLog.val }}
</div>`